# Completing Mirroring Halves

Tags: mirror

Once I have finished the portion of my object that makes use of the mirroring modifier what is the best way to remove the modifier so that the faces, edges and vertices can be selected independently of each other for UV mapping, texturing, etc?

Comment: Apply the modifier and remove doubles?

Comment: I made a human model using mirror and what I am trying to do is get the arms to move independently now that it is done but can't seem to figure out how to separate the arms.

Comment: You need to apply the modifier to make the mirrored geometry real.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the modifiers tab, make sure you are in Object mode.  Currently you can change one side of the object, and it will automatically update the other side.  Click the "Apply" button, and the mirror modifier will be applied to your object.

[image: Before applying]

Now that the modifier is applied, I went back into Edit mode, and dragged a vertex around, and you can see that it does not change the other side of the object.

[image: After applying]

Now you can continue modeling!